# How to write file to desktop in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to write a backup for my database,

I want If a button is clicked the application will export the database to the desktop.

The app exports the file on my database directory if I use laravel database directory path

but if I change the path to desktop location nothing appears on the desktop.

```
        $get_all_table_query = "SHOW TABLES";
    $result = DB::select(DB::raw($get_all_table_query));

    $tables = [
        'users',
        'migrations'
    ];

    $structure = '';
    $data = '';
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $show_table_query = "SHOW CREATE TABLE " . $table . "";

        $show_table_result = DB::select(DB::raw($show_table_query));

        foreach ($show_table_result as $show_table_row) {
            $show_table_row = (array)$show_table_row;
            $structure .= "\n\n" . $show_table_row["Create Table"] . ";\n\n";
        }
        $select_query = "SELECT * FROM " . $table;
        $records = DB::select(DB::raw($select_query));

        foreach ($records as $record) {
            $record = (array)$record;
            $table_column_array = array_keys($record);
            foreach ($table_column_array as $key => $name) {
                $table_column_array[$key] = '`' . $table_column_array[$key] . '`';
            }

            $table_value_array = array_values($record);
            $data .= "\nINSERT INTO $table (";

            $data .= "" . implode(", ", $table_column_array) . ") VALUES \n";

            foreach($table_value_array as $key => $record_column)
                $table_value_array[$key] = addslashes($record_column);

            $data .= "('" . wordwrap(implode("','", $table_value_array),400,"\n",TRUE) . "');\n";
        }
    }
    $file_name = dirname("C:\Users\ADC-2\Desktop") .'/database_backup_on_' . date('y_m_d') . '.sql';
    $file_handle = fopen($file_name, 'w + ');

    $output = $structure . $data;
    fwrite($file_handle, $output);
    fclose($file_handle);
    echo "DB backup ready";
```

It will display DB backup ready but nothing really shows up on the desktop.

Comment: `database_backup_on_` is never set. And has a needless trailing `'`

Comment: fyi, [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-mysqldump.html) can be used to make backups

Comment: @brombeer I have updated my question. I want to do in my local laravel app

Comment: Did you do any debugging? Why use `dirname()` in `$file_name`? Have you checked permissions? Is your script allowed to write to "Desktop"?

Comment: @brombeer What other method can I use apart from dirname(). I did some debugging. It writes to my laravel app but cant write to desktop or the C: drive. I use windows.

Comment: try out `"C:\\Users\\ADC-2\\Desktop"` instead

Comment: @dazed-and-confused worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dirname()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

Use

```
"C:\\Users\\ADC-2\\Desktop"
```

instead of

```
"C:\Users\ADC-2\Desktop"
```